# Warum gibt es einen Artikel in "das einzige, was"?

Tags: grammaticality, article

> 1. Aber das war nicht **das** einzige, was du mir versprochen hast.
> 2. Aber das war nicht einzige, was du mir versprochen hast.

Brauche ich hier einen Artikel und wenn ja, warum?

Answer (score 10):

*"das Einzige"* ist eine [Substantivierung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivierung), der Artikel gehört da hin, und zudem wird *"Einzige"* nach der neuen Rechtschreibung großgeschrieben:

> Aber das war nicht das Einzige, was du mir versprochen hast.

Answer (score 1):

richtig ist die erste Formulierung:

> 1.Aber das war nicht das Einzige, was du mir versprochen hast.